# Implementar checkBox no RecyclerView?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, checkbox, android-recyclerview

Ao clicar no checkBox eu executo o click da lista(abre uma activity). Para marcar o checkBox tem que manter pressionado. Entendo que pode ser esse conflito de um click sobre outro. Como posso então implementar isso para poder clicar normalmente no checkBox e não executar o clique da lista?

aqui o xml do layout do recyclerView:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginStart="1dp"
android:layout_marginEnd="1dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
android:background="@drawable/coner_radius"
android:elevation="1dp">


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvCasa"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:text="casa"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/tvVisitante"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/tv1"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/tvHora"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvVisitante"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:text="visitante"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/tv2"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/tvHora"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvCasa" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_weight="0"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="0"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline3"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    tools:text="0" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_weight="0"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="0"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline3"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv1"
    tools:text="0" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvHora"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="00:00"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.890511" />

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkBox5"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
    android:button="@drawable/check_box"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline3"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Segue o clique do recyclerView:

```
rvJogos.addOnItemTouchListener(
            new RecyclerItemClickListener(
                    getContext(),
                    rvJogos,
                    new RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
                            jogo = listaDeJogos.get(position);
                            Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), JogoActivity.class);
                            intent.putExtra("jogo", jogo);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onLongItemClick(View view, int position) {
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i,
long l) {
                        }
                    }
            )
    );
```

Comment: Não entendi o que você quer muito bem. Você quer ir para outra activity clicando em um checkbox?

Comment: provavelmente você precisa de algum método como stopPropagation pro evento não sair do checkbox

Comment: Pesquisando melhor eu entendi que essa implementação de click (apesar de ser recomendada pelo android) não permitia marcar o checkBox ao clicar sobre ele(essa era a questão). Implementei o click na classe do adapter e funcionou bem. Muito obrigado pelas respostas.